# S is 6 cycle if $ s^i $ is a 6 cycle then find i

Tags: group-theory

Let s be a 6 cycle in $ S_{12}$ then $ s^i $ is also 6 cycle if value of i is

1.2

2.3

3.5

4.12

I think because 6 cycle has order =6 therefore $s^6 $=identity therefor $s^7$=s so for i=7 it is certainly 6 cycle. But 7 is not even an option here. Whats wrong.

Comment: «bcoz»? Please do write complete words. If you do not feel it is worth the time and effort to write properly, you are not providing a lot of motivation for people to think it is worth putting effort in answering...

Comment: In any case, I suggest you pick a random 6-cycle $s$ in $S_12$ and make a list of the first few values of $i$ such that $s^i$ is also a $6$-cycle.

Comment: That is also a way. But I want to know if there is a full fledge method or concept to do this problem

Comment: There is a fully fledged method. But it will be useful for you to find the correct answer first. Notice that I did not say, at all, that computing an example was enough: in fact, it most certainly is not. But an example will probably tell you what goes on in the general case, and you can use *that* to prove what you want.

Comment: Why not post a answer then?

Comment: Because my experience tells me that it is better for you to figure this out! (Notice that by now you have invested more effort in *not* computing an example than what you would have invested in actually computing it :-) )